# Localstorage store if a checkbox has been clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

So we have a checkout and on that checkout, you can select 2 addons now the problem I seem to be having is identifying if those options are ticked or not and displaying the correct styling so lets say I checked both options got to the payment page then canceled it saves that they are checked but doesn't show the styling.

My initial fix for this was to save a var in localstorage when an addon is clicked and then on page load if the localstorage contains it then apply the styling to the addon, however, I can't seem to get it to apply to both it will only apply to 1 see my jQuery below.

```
$(function () {

    addonClass = function(e) {
        $(e).toggleClass("addon-active");
        $(e).find("label .add").toggle(400);
        $(e).find("label .added").toggle(800);
        if ($(window).width() < 600) {
            $(e).find("label .fiver").toggle(400);
        }
    }

    if (localStorage.getItem('addonooh') === "true") {
        addonClass('.first');
        $('.first').find('.add, .fiver').hide();
        $('.last').find('.fiver').show();

    } else if (localStorage.getItem('addon') === "true") {
        addonClass('.last');
        $('.last').find('.add, .fiver').hide();
        $('.first').find('.fiver').show();

    } else if (localStorage.getItem('addonooh') === "true" && localStorage.getItem('addonvm') === "true") {
        addonClass('.first, .last');
        $('.first, .last').find('.fiver').show();

    } else {
    }

    if ($(window).width() > 600) {
        $(".additional-features__item").hover(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass("addon-active-hover");
            $(this).find("label .fiver").stop(true, true).toggle(400);
            $(this).find("label .add").stop(true, true).toggle(800);
            if ($(this).hasClass('addon-active')) {
                $(this).find("label .fiver, label .add").hide();
            }
        });
    }

    if ($(window).width() < 600) {
        $(this).find("label .add").remove();
    }

    $(".additional-features__item").click(function () {

        if ($(this).hasClass('first')) {
            localStorage.addonooh = 'true';
        } else {
            localStorage.addonvm = 'true';
        }


        if ($(this).hasClass('.first') && ($(this).hasClass('.addon-active'))) {
            localStorage.addonooh = '';
        } else if ($(this).hasClass('.last') && ($(this).hasClass('.addon-active'))) {
            localStorage.addonvm = '';
        }

        addonClass(this);
        var checkbox = $(this).find(".mobile-answering__standard-feature");
        checkbox.prop('checked', !checkbox.prop('checked'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is in your `if - elseif - else` block. If `addonooh` is checked in your `localStorage`, execution will go in `if (localStorage.getItem('addonooh') === "true") {`. Since you have the rest of the branching connected with `else if` and `else`, those other branches will never get executed.

What you want to do is change the order of condition checks like this:

```
if (localStorage.getItem('addonooh') === "true" && localStorage.getItem('addonvm') === "true") {
    addonClass('.first, .last');
    $('.first, .last').find('.fiver').show();
} else if (localStorage.getItem('addonooh') === "true") {
    addonClass('.first');
    $('.first').find('.add, .fiver').hide();
    $('.last').find('.fiver').show();

} else if (localStorage.getItem('addon') === "true") {
    addonClass('.last');
    $('.last').find('.add, .fiver').hide();
    $('.first').find('.fiver').show();
}  else {
    // dont care
}
```

This way you first check if both checkboxes are set. **Otherwise** you check if only one of the checkboxes has been set.

**EDIT 1**
In order to have your localstorage cleared when unchecking a checkbox, change the bit of code in your `click` handler of the checkboxes.

```
if ($(this).hasClass('first')) {
    localStorage.setItem("addonooh", $(this).prop('checked'));
} else {
    localStorage.setItem("addonvm", $(this).prop('checked'));
}
```

Note that you should not directly modify localStorage values as you have done in your question, but rather change them with `localStorage.setItem`

Comment: Thanks for this this has got most of it working the only problem i'm having now is when i uncheck one it doesnt clear the local storage i have a feeling it has to do with this bit of code.                                                       
  if ($(this).hasClass('.first') && ($(this).hasClass('.addon-active'))) {
                localStorage.addonooh = '';
            } else if ($(this).hasClass('.last') && ($(this).hasClass('.addon-active'))) {
                localStorage.addonvm = '';
            }

Comment: You havent specified anywhere in your code that you want to clear the localstorage on uncheck. That logic would go under `$(".additional-features__item").click(function () {` click handler. You should not set the value to simply `true` there, but set it to `true` or `false` depending on the $(this).prop('checked') value of the checkbox.